# jQuery - Condensing multiple else ifs inside jquery function

Tags: jquery, json

Couldn't figure out a better way to phrase this title. I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this. I've 
got a function that constructs my JSON call which works just fine. But this seems really really messy as there is some redundant code. I'm trying to 
think of a better way to structure these multiple else if's and if there is a better way to construct my JSON
call.

```
function getUsers() {

    if($.cookie('usernameCookie') && $.cookie('userHeight') && $.cookie('userWeight')){                
    var queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters.json?" + "zipcode=" + zip + "&height=" + heightCookie + "&paymentTypes=" + paymentFilter + "&userTypes=" + userFilter + "&officeTypes=" + officeFilter;            
    } else if($.cookie('usernameCookie') && $.cookie('userHeight')){
    var queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters.json?" + "zipcode=" + zip + "&height=" + heightCookie + "&paymentTypes=" + paymentFilter;
    } else if($.cookie('usernameCookie')){
    var queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters.json?" + "zipcode=" + zip + "&height=" + heightCookie;       
    } else {
    var queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters." + zip + ".json";    
    }

}
```

Any help if greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would be more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = $.cookie('usernameCookie');
var b = $.cookie('userHeight');
var c = $.cookie('userWeight');

if (a) {
     var queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters.json?"
  if (b) {
       queryUsers += //code here
     if (c) {
         queryUsers += //code here
     }
  }
} else {
   //code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUsers() {
    var queryUsers;
    if($.cookie('usernameCookie')) {                
        queryUsers = '/user/services/usercenters.json?'+zipcode;
        if($.cookie('userHeight')){
            queryUsers += "&height="+heightCookie;
        }
        if($.cookie('userWeight')) {
            queryUsers += "&height="+widthCookie;
        }
        // ... etc.
    }
    else {
        queryUsers = '/user/services/usercenters.' + zip + '.json';    
    }

    // queryusers done...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle with a simplified if statement, that also reduces the redundancy in your string building.

```
function getUsers() {
    var name = $.cookie('usernameCookie'),
        height = $.cookie('userHeight'),
        weight = $.cookie('userWeight'),
        queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters.json?zipcode=" + zip;

    if (name) {
        queryUsers += "&height=" + heightCookie; // I've put this here since every instance that had a name also had the height
        if (height && weight) {
            queryUsers += "&paymentTypes=" + paymentFilter + "&userTypes=" + userFilter + "&officeTypes=" + officeFilter;
        } else if (height && !weight) {
            queryUsers += heightCookie + "&paymentTypes=" + paymentFilter;
        }
    } else {
        queryUsers = "/user/services/usercenters." + zip + ".json";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Villike/mLG8S/1/